# DBref in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, ref, dbref

I'm trying to make queries with MongoDB but i have a questions.

**Query and structure**:
[image]

How do I view information about the author at that job with this query? (for example I want to see the name of the autor with the information of the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo does not support joins as in relational databases. You'll need to execute a second query to get the `autore` data.

```
var opera = db.tabella2.findOne();

var autore = db[opera.autore.$ref].find({id:opera.autore.$id});
```

Read more at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/

**EDIT:**

Sometimes you'll want to embed documents to have a better data model. If you have a 1-to-n relation between documents in `tabella2` and `tabella1`, you can have a single `tabella` collection with documents like this, for example:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "nome": "Matteo",
  "cognome": "Cappella",
  "opere": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "titolo": "Eppoi",
      "categoria": "back-end",
    }
  ]
}
```

Read more at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/

Comment: Additional information: Because MongoDB can not resolve references on the database, they are a lot less practical than they seem at first glance. In most situations it is better to either use just a value of an unique identifier from the other collection (_id is good but when you have a more readable identifier, you can also use that) or embed the referenced document.